# What does 唰 (shua1) mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I met the word 唰 shua1 in a Xi Yang Yang book as the sound 唰唰 one character makes while eating.  Two sources agree it is "onomat. quick slick up."  I don't know the English "quick slick up."  Google translate makes a plausible but unclear suggestion of shabu shabu for 唰唰.

What is this word?

Here is the context.  Lazy lamb is enjoying a snack.  The panel caption tells us this is outside of the sheep village school, with a light breeze blowing (羊村“教室外,风儿轻轻吹过).

[image: L]

Comment: The sound of swoosh as in 鳥兒唰地一下飛了過去 (That bird swooshes through).

Comment: Seriously, I don't know whether it's proper to learn Chinese from Xi Yang Yang books, as they're written for very very young children.

Comment: Show us the original text or photo, so we can discuss more out of it.

Comment: @Stan Have you looked at them?  I was expecting simple vocabulary, as found in say French or Italian children's books which I enjoyed when i began reading those languages. But these books are written to be read to children and not by them.  Seeing Growler's answer I find this use of 唰 very sophisticated, cleverly relying on the mouth radical, and not a child-level character.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty That's easy, click "edit", then click the sixth (beginning from the left) icon on the tool bar, shaped like a photo, a window pops up, chose "From my computer" -> "Choose File" -> "Add picture". System will generate a link for the uploaded image and cite it similar to a webpage link.

Comment: 唰 is really child level vocab, children can say it, but not necessarily can write it correct; when it comes to 喜羊羊 is children's book or all age book, it's controversial topic tough, em, maybe because there's no rating system for movies in China.

Comment: Though little kids don't need to know how to write it, onomatopoeic words are almost the first ones they learn after birth :D

Comment: @Stan Yes, that is why I said not a child level character.

Comment: Case closed, being an onomatopoeia word, it gives a sense of breezing wind :D Hooray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[baike.com](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%94%B0) describes it as "swiftly" or "swish"... I believe it is indeed onomatopoeia.

唰 <形> - Adverb

形容迅速的样子 【swiftly】。如:唰地一下跳上墙;唰溜溜(形容极其迅速);唰啦(形容迅疾)

Describes "swiftly" or "quickly" doing something. Like to "swiftly" jump on the wall.

唰 <象> - Adjective for sound

形容迅速擦过去的声音 【swish】。如:唰唰;唰喇喇

Or describes a sound, to "swish" by something.

Comment: So it is the sound lazy lamb makes as his snacks swiftly swish through his mouth.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty haha yes I suppose so

Comment: @ColinMcLarty FYI, "shabu shabu" means "swish swish" in Japanese (and, by extension, a [type of dish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabu-shabu))

Comment: @StumpyJoePete kind of reach, but maybe Ocarina of time's Jabu Jabu (http://es.zelda.wikia.com/wiki/En_la_Tripa_de_Jabu-Jabu) is an extension of Shabu Shabu? :D

Answer (score 3):

唰者 亦「」之正體也

唰 is considered as the standard for its variant 「」

- **[廣韻](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E9%9F%BB)．入聲．薛韻** 謂之曰 「 鳥理毛也 所劣切」
  From [a dictionary](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E9%9F%BB), ' is the act of a bird combing through her feather, consonant following 所, vowel following 劣'.
- **[集韻](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%86%E9%9F%BB)．入聲．薛韻** 謂之曰 「唰 鳥治毛也」
  [Another dictionary](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%86%E9%9F%BB) puts it this way: '唰 is the act of a bird combing through her feather'.
- **[字彙](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E5%BD%99_%28%E6%A2%85%E8%86%BA%E7%A5%9A%29)．口部** 謂之曰 「唰 所劣切 音刷 鳥理毛也  同上」
  [Yet another dictionary](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E5%BD%99_%28%E6%A2%85%E8%86%BA%E7%A5%9A%29) shows that '唰 consonant following 所, vowel following 劣, sounded as 刷, is the act of a bird combing through her feather.  ditto'.
- **[正字通](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3%E5%AD%97%E9%80%9A)．口部** 謂之曰 「 同唰」
  [And another dictionary](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3%E5%AD%97%E9%80%9A) tells that ' is same as 唰'.
- **[康熙字典](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%B7%E7%86%99%E5%AD%97%E5%85%B8)．口部** 謂之曰 「 [廣韻](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KPtH.jpg)所劣切 音刷 鳥理毛也 按 [廣韻](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KPtH.jpg)有「」無「唰」 [玉篇](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8E%89%E7%AF%87)  [集韻](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%86%E9%9F%BB)  [類篇](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E9%A1%9E%E7%AF%87)有「唰」無「」 實即一字 譌分為二」
  [This famous dictionary](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%B7%E7%86%99%E5%AD%97%E5%85%B8) also says something about it: ' as shown in [廣韻](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KPtH.jpg), is the act of a bird combing through her feather, consonant following 所, vowel following 劣, sounded as 刷, editor's note: in [廣韻](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KPtH.jpg) there is an entry for  but not 唰; while in anyone of these [玉篇](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8E%89%E7%AF%87),  [集韻](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%86%E9%9F%BB),  [類篇](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E9%A1%9E%E7%AF%87) 唰 has an entry but  does not. Thus these two are indeed one characters, somehow split into two versions.' Scanned page of **[康熙字典．同文書局版．口部．唰二字](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%B7%E7%86%99%E5%AD%97%E5%85%B8)．口部**:

[image: 康熙字典之同文書局版口部唰二字]

---

### Reference

[台灣教育部異體字字典 (Ministry of Education, Taiwan)](http://dict2.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/)

---

盼諸君賜教

Please leave comment when you have questions.

Comment: , UTF encoding: U+20D2A. Is this character unable to render properly on your PC? BTW, comprehensive answer +1. But I don't think it's necessary to post the whole page of 康熙字典, you can simply leave a link to that source.

Comment: Thanks for 's encoding! Just wanna give a image without any website link on it. 有圖有真相嘛 哈哈

Comment: What does it mean to say "consonant following 所, vowel following 劣"?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty, in today's system, it can be seen as s (所 suo) + ie (劣 lie) = sie (extinct already), somehow it evolves into 數滑切 sh (shu 數) + ua (hua 滑)= shua

Comment: I had not seen such decomposition of characters into vowel and consonant.  What is a good reference for it?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty: 康熙字典 is a good reference. But, if you don't want to learn ancient Chinese, please just forget it. To some extent, this answer is more likely for those who are interested in the etymology.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty 康熙字典 is great copy book that collects all that are handy during the reign of 清聖祖仁皇帝. The boundary between ancient Chinese and modern Chinese are vague. Doctor, if you're a serious learner, go ahead as far as you're interested in. Etymology is good way to learn Chinese; 康熙字典 is an elementary source for digging etymology, since 漢學 came to its peak during 宋 dynasty.